# How to pick image path?

Tags: blackberry

How to pick image path in Blackberry without using a file picker class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
String path1 = System.getProperty(fileconn.dir.photos)
String path2 = System.getProperty(fileconn.dir.memorycard.photos)
```